# Hide starred items in github

Tags: github

How can I hide my starred items from other people in github?
I am not interested in sharing starred items with followers.
I checked github preferences but not found anything relevant.

Comment: Better for either [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) (since it has nothing to do with coding) or direct to GitHub:Support

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot hide what you've starred on GitHub. Once it's starred, it's out there.

Answer (score 23):

The currently accepted answer is no longer valid. In October 2022, Github introduced a feature for hiding your starred items. Enabling this will hide your contributions and activity from your GitHub profile and from social features like followers, stars, feeds, leaderboards and releases.

To activate it:

1. Go to your Github public profile  settings at https://github.com/settings/profile.
2. Scroll down to the `Contributions & Activity` section.
3. Check the box for `Make profile private and hide activity`.
   [image]
4. Click on `Update Preferences` button to save changes.

After activation, your public profile will look like this to other people:
[image]

The `Stars` tab is missing so no one can see your starred items.

Comment: at the time of this comment this feature is no longer in beta